# how to convert os.stat_result to a JSON that is an object?

Tags: json, python-3.x, encoding

I know that `json.dumps` can be used to convert variables into a JSON representation. Sadly the conversion of python3's class `os.stat_result` is an string consisting of an array representing the values of the class instance.

```
>>> import json
>>> import os
>>> json.dumps(os.stat('/'))
'[16877, 256, 24, 1, 0, 0, 268, 1554977084, 1554976849, 1554976849]'
```

I would however much prefer to have it convert the `os.stat_result` being converted to an JSON being an object. **How can I achieve this?**

It seems that the trouble is that `os.stat_result` does not have a `.__dict__` thing.

seeing the result of this:

```
 >>> import os
 >>> str(os.stat('/'))
 'os.stat_result(st_mode=16877, st_ino=256, st_dev=24, st_nlink=1, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_size=268, st_atime=1554977084, st_mtime=1554976849, st_ctime=1554976849)'
```

makes me hope there is a swift way to turn an python class instance (e.g. `os.stat_result") into a JSON representation that is an object.

which while is JSON, but the results are

Answer (score 20):

as gst mentioned, manually would be this:

```
def stat_to_json(fp: str) -> dict:
    s_obj = os.stat(fp)
    return {k: getattr(s_obj, k) for k in dir(s_obj) if k.startswith('st_')}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would however much prefer to have it convert the os.stat_result being converted to an JSON being an object. How can I achieve this?

if by JSON you mean have a dict with keys `st_mode`, `st_ino`, etc.. then the answer is .. manually.

Comment: I mean exactly that `{"st_mode":0777, "st_ino":.....}"`. To be sure: does your answer suggest manually as the "way of least resistance", or because all other ways, such as for example the way *"to provide `class os.stat_result` with a `__dict__` object, thereby making it convertable to JSON object notation"*  can be ruled out with certainty?

Answer (score 0):

with a "prevaled" list of keys:

```py
# http://thepythoncorner.com/dev/writing-a-fuse-filesystem-in-python/

def dict_of_lstat(lstat_res):
  lstat_keys = ['st_atime', 'st_ctime', 'st_gid', 'st_mode', 'st_mtime', 'st_nlink', 'st_size', 'st_uid', 'st_blocks']
  return dict((k, getattr(lstat_res, k)) for k in lstat_keys)

lstat_dict = dict_of_lstat(os.lstat(path))

def dict_of_statvfs(statvfs_res):
  statvfs_keys = ['f_bavail', 'f_bfree', 'f_blocks', 'f_bsize', 'f_favail', 'f_ffree', 'f_files', 'f_flag', 'f_frsize', 'f_namemax']
  return dict((k, getattr(statvfs_res, k)) for k in statvfs_keys)

statvfs_dict = dict_of_statvfs(os.statvfs(path))
```

longer but faster than a `k.startswith('st_')` filter

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old but I kind of did not like any of the answers so here is my function to convert stat results to a dictionary (which can be loaded by json.dumps):

```
import os

def stat_to_dict(filestat):
    if type(filestat) == os.stat_result:
        returnval = {}
        for stat in dir(filestat):
            if stat[:3] == 'st_':
                returnval[stat] = getattr(filestat, stat)
        return returnval
    else:
        raise ValueError(f'argument must be os.stat_result not {type(filestat)}')


def statdict(filepath):
    return stat_to_dict(os.stat(filepath))
```