# Iterate over all results contained in os.stat_result and keep the descriptor

Tags: python

using import pathlib as pl,
I have this:

```
f = pl.Path(fname)
fstats = f.stat()
print(fstats)
```

which prints this:

```
os.stat_result(st_mode=33206, st_ino=22517998136958185, st_dev=705230555, st_nlink=1, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_size=176, st_atime=1621921747, st_mtime=1578950983, st_ctime=1578950983)
```

How can I iterate over each of the results without losing the before-equals-sign descriptors (example "st_mode")?

if I do this:

```
        for st in fstats:
        print(st)
```

I only get the values contained in each stat

if I pass it into a dataframe, I get a dataframe of the stat results only with no descriptors:

```
    dfs = pd.DataFrame(data=f.stat())
    print(dfs)
```

If I turn f.stat() into a list and pass that into a dataframe, it still loses the descriptors (like "st_mode"):

```
        f = pl.Path(fname)
    fstats = f.stat()
    print('-----------------')
    print(fstats)
    print('-----------------')
    dfs0 = pd.DataFrame(data=f.stat())
    print(dfs0)
    print('-----------------')
    dfs1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[list(f.stat())])
    print(dfs1)
    print('-----------------')
```

out:
[image]

Comment: I found this thread to be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64885380/how-can-i-pull-out-the-specific-attributes-in-os-stat .  It suggests treating os.stat_result as a namedtuple.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I couldn't find an answer.  I instead had to parse the string f.stat():

```
    fstats = str(f.stat()).replace("os.stat_result(","")
    fstats = fstats.replace(", ", ",")
    fstats = fstats.replace(")", "")
    fstats = re.split(",", fstats)
    #print(fstats)
    for item in fstats:
        fstat = re.split("=", item)
        entry = [fstat[0], fstat[1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `list()`

**Ex:**

```
dfs = pd.DataFrame(data=[list(f.stat())])
```

Comment: hmm- that seems to only array the results across columns instead of rows, but still with no associated descriptor like "st_mode":

Answer (score 0):

Here is [a.k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8162407/a-k)'s good solution for this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58684090/9770860

```
def stat_to_json(fp: str) -> dict:
    s_obj = os.stat(fp)
    return {k: getattr(s_obj, k) for k in dir(s_obj) if k.startswith('st_')}
```

Comment: **NOTE** While you have provided the link to the code sample copied from another answer, you should also provide the name of the person who provided the code rather than 'someone'. See the notes [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)